# openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error opening input file vfs://root/temp/

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Im trying to sign a PDF with PHP in Google App Engine standard environment.

When I try to run openssl_pkcs7_sign, the Stackdriver warns that the file could not be found. I have tried using Google Cloud Storage too, but it does not work.

```
$tempdoc = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'tcpdf_43fa8d07af13688a76d62542bae96475_doc_b900c3e9fa55248421a8f2be33b23a29_');
$f = fopen($tempdoc, 'wb');
fwrite($f, 'hi');
fclose($f);
openssl_pkcs7_sign($tempdoc, '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----……', array('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----….', ''), array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED);
```

> PHP Warning:  openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error opening input file vfs://root/temp/tcpdf_43fa8d07af13688a76d62542bae96475_doc_b900c3e9fa55248421a8f2be33b23a29_5a77beba622c81.38516089!

Any idea?

Comment: The local file system in App Engine is restricted, as App Engine runs in a security sandbox. Please check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#tempnam_and_sys_get_temp_dir_support) and adapt your implementation to it.

Comment: hi tudormi. can you explain your tip? i used tempnam and sys_get_temp_dir. i used fwrite too. tks

Comment: hi Bob D. I'm sorry for my previous comment, it was a superficial action from my part, as I did not pay enough attention. There's no need to adapt your code. My guess is that the way openssl_pkcs7_sign() tries to write to the file is not in accordance with App Engine's security rules. I am not sure yet. I've tested the [openssl_sign()](http://cct.me.ntut.edu.tw/ccteducation/chchting/aiahtm/computer/phphelp/function.openssl-sign.php.htm) function. It just generates a signature and does no alter the data. This one works. Do you consider a workaround, not having the file in the local filesystem?

Comment: hi tudormi. im tried to use google cloud storage, but doesn´t work too. same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `openssl` extension uses a proprietary file handling mechanism which is not supported in Google App Engine Standard. The solution would be to use App Engine Flexible, which allows writing to local disk.

Comment: I found PHP Exception is represented as object sometimes and string in other times (shown in stackdriver logging), do you have any recommendation to get Exception as object for all PHP Exceptions? (I prefer use Exception object instead of string, because object has more information, even though there are a lot of Exceptions represented by string in logs)

Comment: I am not aware at this point how to get PHP Exceptions as object only. I strongly suggest you create a new Stackoverflow post so that you would benefit from the community (potentially multiple, better answers) and the community would benefit from you (finding your question via key words).